# Dynamically Generating Routes in Gatsby JS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, web-applications, gatsby

I am trying to create a complex CRUD React Application using Gatsby JS. The ability for the user to Create Posts, Edit Posts, Delete Posts will also need to be available. This app will have many users. We are not using a third-party CMS. Everything will be done within the Gatsby App. There will also need to be several different pages that will need to handle state, display, and sort the different posts based upon options. My question is, is this sort of project overload for Gatsby JS since it breaks the page model? Gatsby doesn't have a native way to generate dynamic routes or views, only pages. Its sort of a social networking app, is Gatsby JS the wrong tool for the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create pages "dynamically" using the `createPages` API.

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#createPages

There's also a great series of videos from [Scott Tolinski](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1NaVkKdrwc) that demonstrate the use of this API.

However, GatsbyJS is a **static** static site generator, it's designed for performance and more content-based sites. The only way you're going to get CRUD functionality is through API calls from the front-end which could have some security implications that you need to consider.

As an alternative, you might want to take a look at [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/). Same kind of idea but the pages are served by Express.js rather than just served off the file system so you have a lot more options for more dynamic sites.